# How to access internal class using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, class, internal

How can I access an internal class of an assembly?
Say I want to access System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost. Here the DesignerHost is an internal and sealed class.

How can I write a code to load the assembly and the type?.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In general, you *shouldn't* do this - if a type has been marked internal, that means you're not meant to use it from outside the assembly. It could be removed, changed etc in a later version.

However, reflection *does* allow you to access types and members which aren't public - just look for overloads which take a `BindingFlags` argument, and include `BindingFlags.NonPublic` in the flags that you pass.

If you have the *fully qualified* name of the type (including the assembly information) then just calling [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) should work. If you know the assembly in advance, and know of a public type within that assembly, then using `typeof(TheOtherType).Assembly` to get the assembly reference is generally simpler, then you can call [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx).

Comment: @dattebayo : just to complete Jon's answer, note that your code needs to run in full trust, or reflection on non-public members will fail

Comment: Sometimes you just have to, until it breaks. I have a WPF `DataGrid` command whose parameter is `SelectedItems`. In the command, the parameter is received as `object` but it of type `SelectedCellCollection`, which is inaccessible in my code. I need this kind of cheat in the hope of casting the `object` parameter to a `SelectedCellCollection`.

Answer (score 19):

To load the assembly and type you quoted in your example:

```
Assembly design = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Design.dll");
Type designHost = design.GetType("System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost");
```

Comment: You can  just `Assembly.Load("System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")`

Comment: If you only need one type you can skip loading the assembly explicitly: `var designHost = Type.GetType("System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");`