# (MTM) Microsoft Test Manager - Run Test Case Programatically

Tags: .net, testing, reflection

I'm trying to run a test case programatically using the internal Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client methods but I found that almost all the methods are internal, so I cannot use them.

Do you have an idean how can I use these class/methods? Of couse I'm referencing to these dll's in my project and I need to use them.

I attached two images of the reflection of the dll.

[image]
[image]

Thank you for your help

Sebastian

Comment: see this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259222/how-to-access-internal-class-using-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but:
Since the methods are internal, they are not supposed to be used. Even when using reflection to call them is a risk as MS can change the API of these methods at any time (hotfix, service pack, vNext). So anything that you build on top of these undocumented API's is also unsupported (you are totally on your own in case anything goes wrong!)

AFAIK, the only tool supported to actualy run Test Cases is the Test Runner from MTM itself.

Comment: So tests can only be run through the MTM GUI? Is there no way to start a test run on a schedule?

Comment: You can use build triggers see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182465.aspx

And after you create the Build definition you can run a scheduled build.